# How to get all entries posted within a specific year?

Tags: entries, datetime

I am trying to get all entries posted from 2018 and only 2018. All the other methods I've seen are for from a specific date or between two dates. Is there a simple way to get all posts from 2018 without having to specify `get all entries between 1 January 2018 and 31 December 2018`?

The markup below is where I have got to, but this is getting all entries from 2018 onwards. But when I change the `>=` parameter to `==` it appears to break it.

```
{% set event = craft.entries.section('events').startDate('>=' ~ formYear).one() %}
```

Comment: Did you [look a this guide](https://craftcms.com/guides/creating-an-archive-page-for-entries#yearly-archive-pages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
{% set event = craft.entries({
    section: 'events',
    startDate: 'and, >= ' ~ formYear ~ ', < ' ~ (formYear + 1)
}).one() %}
```